# Javascript to create a textarea with foreign object in SVG not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following HTML/javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg id = "svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width = "800" height = "400"  >
  <foreignobject id = "x" x = "50" y = "50" width = "300" height = "100">
  <textarea rows = "3" cols = "30" border = "1px"> hello </textarea>
</foreignobject>  
</svg>
<script>
var fo = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignobject");
fo.setAttribute("id", "y");
fo.setAttribute("x", "200");
fo.setAttribute("y", "300");
fo.setAttribute("width", "300");
fo.setAttribute("height", "100");
var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
ta.rows = 3;
ta.cols = 30;
ta.innerHTML = "world";
fo.appendChild(ta);
document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(fo);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a text area inside a foreign object inside the SVG and it shows up as expected. However, I also have javascript that tries to create exactly the same thing, but the text area won't show up. Tried this on chrome browser. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SVG element names are case sensitive. Try `foreignObject` instead of `foreignobject`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just that you missed the XHTML namespace and `foreignObject` instead od `foreignobject`: http://jsfiddle.net/49sg5j5m/4/

```
var ta = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "textarea");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id = "svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width = "800" height = "400"  >
        <foreignObject id = "x" x = "50" y = "50" width = "300" height = "100">
            <textarea rows = "3" cols = "30" border = "1px"> hello </textarea>
        </foreignObject>  
    </svg>

<script>
var fo = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
fo.setAttribute("id", "y");
fo.setAttribute("x", "200");
fo.setAttribute("y", "300");
fo.setAttribute("width", "300");
fo.setAttribute("height", "100");
var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
ta.rows = 3;
ta.cols = 30;
ta.innerHTML = "world";
fo.appendChild(ta);
document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(fo);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```